# Combining different expressions

Tags: regex

I'm still new to regex and want to combine different expressions together. Right now all these expressions work when used seperatly but I can't seem to combine them to a working string.

I want to only match strings with one % in the beginning without whitespace behind.

Example

```
%string  => Match
% string => No Match
%%string => No Match
```

Right now I have these expressions:

```
(^[^%]*%[^%]*$) - Matches only one % but with whitespace
(%\S+)([^\n]+)  - Matches strings with the % and no whitespace behind but also matches the %% string that shouldn't be matched
```

I tried combining them with copying them after another

```
(^[^%]*%[^%]*$)(\S+)([^\n]+)
```

But that won't work. I know I do something wrong when combining them, I just don't know what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
^%[^\s%]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FVPAG7/1).

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `%` - a percent symbol
- `[^\s%]*` - a negated character class matching zero or more chars other than whitespace and `%`
- `$` - end of string anchor

Comment: That is much simpler. Thanks! I also wanted to match the entire string even if its seperated with whitespace for the entire line. Like "%string string string". I tried it with this group ([^\n]+) that matches everything in the entire line. When I append it now it doesn't work, I put it in a second group that matches after your solution.

Comment: Does it mean you do not want to allow a whitespace as the *second* symbol only? Well, that makes the requirements a bit unclear. Try `^%[^\s%][^%]*$`. If you need to also match a string that only consists of `%`, you would need a lookahead - `^%(?!\s)[^%]*$`

Comment: Exactly! That works. Thank you again! I will take a look at character classes so I can learn it by myself.